# Thingsboard Realtime graph not displaying

Tags: graph, thingsboard

I've set up a device on my Thingsboard server. Data is being received from my device.

When I add a chart to the device's dashboard and set the timewindow to any value to "last" and the data aggregation function to anything but "none", nothing shows in the graph.

Any data aggregation function (besides "none") causes no data to be displayed in the graph.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thingsboard supports different data types. If you are submitting your telemetry as String, then it is saved as the string. And in this case, 'SUM' and 'AVG' functions will return empty dataset because it is not possible to calculate the sum and average value on String data. But 'MIN/MAX/COUNT' aggregation functions will work.

For example:
{"key1":"10"} - value is saved as string ("10") - SUM and AVG will not work

{"key1":10} - value is saved as integer (10) - all aggregation functions will work

You can enable debug mode in 'save telemetry' node to find original messages that are published to the Thingsboard.

You can also find more details on GitHub issues:

[#1149](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/1149)

[#817](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/817)

Comment: So basically, you have to send data that contains numbers as integers and not strings.